# Is the existence of a continuous top form sufficient for orientability of a smooth manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, orientation

I'm currently working through Tu's *Introduction to Manifolds*. He first defines orientability in terms of the existence of orientations on the tangent spaces which can be locally represented by a continuous frame, and then goes on to show that this is equivalent with the existence of a smooth top form which vanishes nowhere on the manifold. My question is: why do we need this form to be smooth? Wouldn't continuity already suffice? I can't figure out the motivation from the proof he gives.

Comment: These are all equivalent. $M$ admits a nowhere zero continuous top form iff it admits a nowhere zero smooth top form.

Comment: @ArcticChar could you point me to a proof for this, by any chance?

Comment: The only missing part is that $M$ admits a continuous nowhere zero top form $\Rightarrow M$ is orientable. It shouldn't be difficult....

Comment: Do you know that you can approximate continuous functions (on Euclidean space or on manifolds) by smooth functions? But since you want an intermediate value theorem argument, most likely, continuity is all you're going to need.

Comment: @TedShifrin are you referring to Weierstrass' theorem on polynomials?

Comment: @ArcticChar ah, I see it now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's one way to do it, yes. Or you can use smoothing techniques coming by convolving with appropriate "approximate identity" functions.

Comment: @TedShifrin indeed, Landau kernel smoothing is in fact often used to prove Weierstrass in the first place, like in Rudin's book